# Ansible and debugging script

Tags: ansible

I want to run a python script locally, and print (debug) the output. Running the script outside of ansible gives my this:

```
$ python ../scripts/test-winrm-v5.py 
i-746726df
```

Here's my playbook:

```
$ cat test4.yml 
- name: list instance ids
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    local_action: shell python ../scripts/test-winrm-v5.sh
    register: result
    debug: msg="{{ result }}"
```

Here's what I get when I run the playbook:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i ../inventory/phani test4.yml

PLAY [list instance ids] ****************************************************** 

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
```

Why doesn't the output from the script get displayed?

Comment: Correction: changed .sh to .py in the playbook, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had some control character on the debug line. I typed that line again, and now it's working. Here's the playbook:

```
- name: list instance ids
  hosts: windows
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="System {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  - local_action: shell python ../scripts/test-winrm-v5.py
    register: result
  - debug: msg="Result of running script is {{ result.stdout }}"
```